# Joining computer science R&D field

Tags: computer-science

I have a strong passion towards doing research in computer science. I am working as a software developer in Java for 5.2 yrs. I am reading algorithms and data structures to make my base correct in terms of R&D. Now I am not sure what else to read and make myself equipped as a computer scientist? What are all the various companies that can offer me a researcher job? and what do they expect out of me?

I tried googling but its of less help.

I am ready to read and learn anything. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Good question, but I think this belongs to programmers.SE?

Comment: I am sorry. programmers SE means? :(

Comment: It means this site http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted the question in Programmers SE. All I got was negative votings :'(

Comment: Yes i can understand that there are certain people here who are bit harsh but there good people too, for example your comment got an up-vote too

Comment: Correct :) There will be a day when those people who are harsh will wait for me to comment in their site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In other words i can say you want to pursue a Phd, the reason you found less information for a company who wants a Computer scientist or Phd because normally these people are considered over-qualified.

2) But there are some companies that due recruit Phd's

3) But if want a career in Academia then i would advise you to go for Phd.

4) My final advice will be think and do a bit searching on Google about companies who need such people and then finally take a decision